# Object oriented C: Building vtables

Tags: c, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to teach myself basics of object oriented C. I'm trying to build vtables and then use those to simulate "inheritance" of structs (try to copy class inheritance in C++).

I have a question.. I believe it is possible, but I don't know how to do it. Can variable of "derived" struct be modified from pointer of "base" struct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//should represent Base
typedef struct Animal
{
    int age;
    void *vtable;
} Animal;

//Cat and dog will inherit Animal. They both have same 'age' variable, and different other parameters
typedef struct Dog
{
    int age;
    double weight;
    void *vtable;
} Dog;

typedef struct Cat
{
    int age;
    int numberOfLives;
    void *vtable;
} Cat;

//some test functions
void Speak_Dog(Animal* a)
{
    printf("Woof!\n");
}

void Speak_Cat(Animal* a)
{
    printf("Meow!\n");
}

//this is where I'm stuck, I would like to keep sending pointer to Animal
double Dog_GetCost(Animal *a)
{
    return 0;//should return age*weight
}

double Cat_GetCost(Animal *a)
{
    return 0;  //should return age*num_lives
}

//build tables
void* Dog_Vtable[2] = {Speak_Dog, Dog_GetCost};
void* Cat_Vtable[2] = {Speak_Cat, Cat_GetCost};

void Construct_Dog(Dog* d)
{
    d->age = 0;
    d->weight = 0;
    d->vtable = Dog_Vtable;
}

void Construct_Cat(Cat* c)
{
    c->age = 0;
    c->numberOfLives = 0;
    c->vtable = Cat_Vtable;
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    Dog d;
    Cat c;
    Animal* a;

    ((void (*)(Animal*))Dog_Vtable[0])((Animal*)&d);  //print out "woof" - good
    ((void (*)(Animal*))Cat_Vtable[0])((Animal*)&c);  //print out "meow" - good

    printf("Do you want to make dog or a cat? (0/1) ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 0)
    {
        a = &d;  //animal is Dog
        a = (Animal*)malloc(sizeof(Dog));  //allocate memory for Dog
        Construct_Dog(a);  //construct it
    }
    else
    {
        a = &c;  //similar for cat
        a = (Animal*)malloc(sizeof(Cat));
        Construct_Cat(a);
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, let's say I try to modify 2nd int variable (weight or NumLives, depending), how would I change it using `*a`?
I'm trying to learn from `Object oriented programming with ANSI-C`, but I fail to figure this out.

Comment: If you know a is of type Dog in advance, just do ((Dog*)a)->weight = 33.3; But in this case you lose the abstraction of oop.

Comment: I can still use a `switch` or something similar and determine what Animal it is. So this looks pretty good I think. Will test in a bit!

Comment: Your code is broken. C doesn't define casting from-to arbitrary type.

Comment: That book is really complicated. I suggest you start with something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `((Dog *)a) -> weight = 42.0;` or `((Cat *)a) -> numberOfLives = 9;`